# Shadow underneath QPushButton does not disappear no matter what I do

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

So, I am adding a QSS style sheet to a C++ application. So far everything is going well except for this problem. I cannot, for the life of me, remove that weird shadow underneath the text of a disabled QPushButton, as seen below.

[image]

I have tried a couple of things so far. The first thing I did was attempt to change the text-shadow value of the QSS sheet to none:

```
QPushButton::disabled
{
    color: #888888;
    background-color: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

I tried a couple of things around this, like removing one ":" between QPushButton and disabled like this `QPushButton:disabled`. I also tried chaning the `box-color` which didn't work either.

I then tried to modify the palette of the GUI in QT Designer, I set disabled Text, BightText, ButtonText and Shadow alpha values to 0, hopefully making the shadow transparent, but that did not work either.

I tried asking an AI, but the response was pretty much just to use `text-shadow: none;` so that didn't help. Has anyone else ever encountered this? How do i remove that shadow?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you applying a stylesheet to your `QApplication` or the parent of this button? Where is this button added/contained/used? What OS and Qt version are you using? Does this blur effect affect other disabled widgets or/and other non Qt applications in your system? A disabled button looks fine on my end.